# Why the lazy loaded component in Angular 11 is loaded in a new page, not in the main page to the right of the sidebar?

Tags: javascript, angular, module, components, lazy-loading

I have several modules which I want to call lazy.

In my project I have a dashboard module whose component is loaded after a successful login.

This works.

In this module I have more submodules. For example overview.

I have built a simple sidebar. When the link overview is clicked, the module overview should be loaded in the main view to the right of the sidebar.

But unfortunately it is loaded into a new page.
I.e. the sidebar is no longer visible, but only the view of the overview module.

I hope it is understandable

**My Code:**

*app.module.ts:*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AuthModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DashboardModule,

    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app-routing.modules.ts:*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/login'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

*dashboard.module.ts:*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoreModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule,
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

*dashboard-routing.module.ts:*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'overview',
    component: OverviewComponent
    // loadChildren: () => import('./overview/overview.module').then(m => m.OverviewModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'mandants',
    component: MandantsComponent

    // loadChildren: () => import('./mandants/mandants.module').then(m => m.MandantsModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

*overview.module.ts:*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OverviewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OverviewRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class OverviewModule { }
```

*overview-routing.module.ts:*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OverviewComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OverviewRoutingModule { }
```

*dashboard.component.html:*

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10" id="test">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*app.component.html:*

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

*sidebar.component.ts:*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

*sidebar.component.html:*

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>Cockpit</h3>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <li class="active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/overview">Übersicht</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/mandants">Mandanten</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

The sidebar component is loaded in *core.modules.ts:*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

I have just started to learn angular and therefore still a beginner.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

If you need more information let me know.

Comment: Here is a simple solution. Check my Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-routing-with-modules-with-bootstrap-r6xzsv?embed=1&file=src/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In app-routing-module.ts the 'dashboard' path should be configured to dashboard module so that the dashboard routing module will be enabled. And you can lazy load Overview module and Mandants module inside the dashboard routing module.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/login'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even now the components from the DashboardModule are loaded in a new page and not next to the sidebar

Comment: Can you show me how you are routing to overview in the <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>. The path should be '/dashboard/overview'.

Comment: In the sidebar.component.html, the routerLink should be "/dashboard/overview":  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/dashboard/overview">Übersicht</a>.

Comment: Also make sure "<router-outlet></router-outlet>" is only there in app.componet.html and dashboard.component.html

Comment: Both checked, and tried the routerlink like "/dashboard/overview, but the compenent of overview is stilled showed in a new site and not next to the sidebar.

Comment: The loading of the component works in principle, but is displayed incorrectly. Not next to the sidebar but as a new page and the side is then gone.

Comment: Try clearing the cache, disabling cache in browser and restarting the angular server.

Comment: I did, but nothing changed. I think I should rethink my structure. thank u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232485/discussion-between-ren-and-hubi).

Comment: may be you can share your code in stackblitz?